# How much connected is the Night of the Living Dead film series?

Tags: chronology, night-of-the-living-dead

*Night of the Living Dead film series* are the 6 zombie horror films created by George A. Romero but [as per Wikipedia they are loosely connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Living_Dead_(film_series)) but how loosely? I have not seen any of those 6 films and thinking about watching them but want to know how much they are connected and what is their chronological order and if I can skip any of them?

And what about the remake Dawn of the Dead (2004)? Is it connected to any of them or fully independent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Loosely" connected in that they're chronological, but don't contain any recurring characters.  In the first one, zombies had never existed prior to the events depicted in the movie.  In all subsequent ones, zombies have existed previously.  You do not need to view them in order, although it's more enjoyable as you watch special effects capabilities improve over time.

The remake of Dawn of the Dead is independent.  While the location is the same as the original (both take place in a shopping mall), the remake begins with no one knowing about zombies and also departs from the cathartic zombie trope and is the first zombie movie to show them in full sprint.

Comment: Can you give some examples to the claim that "zombies existed previously" in the subsequent movies?

Comment: The original Dawn of the Dead opens in a news room where scientists are discussing zombies, and the characters allude to the fact that people are scared and trying to find safe places to go.  You can see the opening sequence here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uD1uCAQdIXE  This would indicate that right from the opening seconds of Dawn of the Dead, people know of zombies and are fearing for their lives.

Comment: Yeah, but that still doesn't exclude the possibility that the zombie outbreak is a recent phenomenon, that started in the first movie.

Comment: I'm confused, because I think that's exactly what my answer said.  The outbreak started in the first movie, all the rest of them began with the premise that zombies already exist.

Comment: The way you phrased it: "Loosely connected", " In all subsequent ones, zombies have existed previously" implies that the movies are set in different universes. Maybe rephrase it as, "in subsequent movies the zombie outbreak that started in the first movie has already been going for some time".

Comment: "The first zombie movie to show them in full sprint" isn't exactly accurate. The remake of _Dawn of the Dead_ was 2004. In 1985, _The Return of the Living Dead_ showed zombies running too. That movie has nothing to do with the world that George Romero created; those zombies are completely unrelated.

Comment: @BrettFromLA - My bad.  I largely ignored the "Living Dead" movies since Romero had nothing to do with them, so I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: You've got your claim on "first zombie movie to show them in full sprint" incorrect. *28 Days Later* & *Resident Evil*, at least, predate it

Comment: "cathartic zombie trope" Did you mean "lethargic"?